# how to add short sounds while swiping images in uiscrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, audio

how to add sounds in uiscrollview,while swiping different images with different sounds.
please help me.
Thanks regards 
Rajan

Comment: yeah i have tried using avaudioplayer..

Comment: i dont have any idea about this.

Comment: dont post already asked this same question...

Comment: did u use to show images for gallery

Answer (score 0):

When scrolling stop then you can check that page is changed or not. If Changed than play sound else not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods to achieve this task you can use

`scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` to achieve this with the using one ivar to store the current display position of the `UIScrollView` and in this method using `contentOffset.x` property of the `UIScrollView` you can achieve what you need.

Yep you need to use `AVAudioPlayer` to play sound.
Think this will help you.
Happy Codding :)

Enjoy Coding :)