# how to add short sounds while swiping images in uiscrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to add short sounds while swiping images in uiscrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891522/how-to-add-short-sounds-while-swiping-images-in-uiscrollview)

this is my code

here i want to add sounds while swipe images.

```
int x,y,count;
    but=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top2.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"top1.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"top3.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"top4.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"top5.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"top6.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"top7.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"top8.png"],nil];

    x=0;
    y=0;
    count=0;
    for (int i=0; i<=7; i++) {
        count++;
        for (int i=7; i>=0; i--) {
            count--;

            UIButton *but2=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 320, 141)];

            //[but setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mzl.jpg" ]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [but2 setImage:[but objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            NSLog(@"%@",but);

            x=x+320;
            // x=0;
            //y=0;

            if(count==8)
            {
                //count++;
            }
            //[scr addSubview:images];
            //[images release];
            [scrollview1 addSubview:but2];
        }
    }
    scrollview1.pagingEnabled=TRUE;
    [scrollview1 setContentSize:CGSizeMake(x, y)];
```

Comment: how many times have you asked this exact same question?  voting to close. do not post duplicate questions.